# Format pl/sql code aligning comments using Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a program that scripts all of the objects in an Oracle database to files and then uses Oracle SQL Developer to format the files. For example:

sdcli64.exe format input="%source%" output="%target%"

The problem is that the comments seem to be left as they are in the original text. I would like them to be aligned with the next line of code.

For example, the code is being formatted as follows, with the comments not placed in a good position, usually in the first column.

```
IF OUTER COND
/* Comment
Block
*/ 
    IF INNER CONDITION
--SOME COMMENT
        x = 2;
    END
END
```

Ideally, I would like the comments to align as shown below:

```
IF OUTER COND
    /* Comment
    Block
    */
    IF INNER CONDITION
        --SOME COMMENT
        x = 2;
    END
END
```

Oracle SQL developer doesn't look like it has any easy settings to accomplish this. If does have what looks like robust but cryptic custom formatting capabilities as described here:

https://www.salvis.com/blog/2020/04/13/formatting-code-with-sql-developer/

My impression is that the formatting is based off of the parsed syntax tree and that doesn't include comments, so that there is no way to get the desire result.

What do you think? is there a way to get the desire formatting of comments using SQL developer?